# Is there a way to send a message programmatically without user having to tap on screen to confirm sending the message, but just to use voice commands?

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, speech

I would like to make a Voice Assistant app and I would like to have functionality for sending SMS messages to certain people. Can I send that message, and after I dictated my text I want to say "Send" in order to send the message. So, there should not be any physical interaction between the user and the screen. Only voice commands. Is that possible to do?

I researched some solutions but I saw that this is not possible and that user interaction is needed. Now I am not sure if by that, they mean physical user interaction by touching the device.

Comment: can't be done programmatically. Requires user interaction i.e. the user has to press the button

Comment: So voice interaction is not an option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I send an SMS on iOS without having to get the user to ok it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659808/how-do-i-send-an-sms-on-ios-without-having-to-get-the-user-to-ok-it)

Comment: The MFMessageComposeViewController is a builtin viewcontroller of iOS. We can't send/simulate actions on it. how would you deliver voice command to something which is not a part of your app?

Comment: What about **Twilio** 3rd party service, I saw some comments that people are using their API in order to achieve that. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: @MarkoZivko I've added an answer to address your both queries. if you think my answer full fill your requirement, then please accept and upvote it thanks

Comment: Thanks very much! I upvoted your answer but I still don't have enough reputation points to see the upvote.

Comment: @MarkoZivko I understand but you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

> there should not be any physical interaction between the user and the
>   screen.

If you are using iOS default way for sending message i.e. `MFMessageComposeViewController` then No, it's not possible. As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28659908/2299040) (basically to prevent spamming)

> What about Twilio 3rd party service

With third party integration, **you can achieve what you want** but keep in mind that companies like Twilio charge a certain amount against the service they provide and that charge has to be bear by you or your company

Answer (score 1):

iOS will always present a dialog to confirm send. This is by design to avoid you sending SMS messages through stealth as they can cost money. You could also send premium rate sms messages which could cost the user money.

You could send the message to a cloud service or your own service and forward the messages from there as mentioned above.